# How does an installer see a manifest? Delphi

Tags: delphi, installation, manifest

So, I know a lot of questions have been asked around here about manifests but I haven't quite found what I was looking for in terms of explanation. Basically I need a manifest for the installer of a Delphi application. Now most guides I see on manifests say to create a .manifest file and a .rc file then add {.$R 'file.res' 'file.rc'} in the application so that it sees it when it starts and to place the files alongside the .exe.

Now where I'm confused is that my manifest is for an installer, I can't place the files alongside the installer, logically, as it is its job to put the files where they need to go. Now I'm not going to send a package with an installer and 2 other random files to people obviously. So I'm just trying to figure out how the manifest can work for an installer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you compile the manifest into a compiled resource and link that resource into the executable. That way you can deliver a single executable file, and the loader is able to find the manifest when it loads that executable.

That's exactly what is happening when you use `{$R ...}` as shown in the question. That directive instructs the compiler to link the compiled resource into the executable. Once you've done that it is pointless to distribute the .rc and .manifest files because they will be ignored by the loader. The loader prefers to use a manifest linked to the executable if it exists. And in any case, the loader is never interested in a .rc file, that's just used to compile the resource.

Although it is possible to include manifest files as files external to the executable, that is not advisable. The reason being is that it makes it too easy for people to copy the executable but not the manifest, delete or rename one of the files. Because the manifest is separate it can get dislocated from the executable in this way and then the loader does not find it.

So, link the compiled manifest resource to your executable, as you already appear to be doing. And do not distribute the .rc or .manifest file.

Comment: So, you mean I just need to keep that line in there and when I compile it will automatically add it to the ressources so I don't need anything else??

Comment: That's the idea. Of course it must be `{$R 'file.res' 'file.rc'}` rather than `{.$R 'file.res' 'file.rc'}`.